# find number of element of array when it use as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I write a function in c++ that should count number of elements an array has. function receive array as its parameter. so I try the following method:

```
int countArray(int a[])
{
    int size = 0;
    while(a[size] != NULL)
    {
        size++;
    }
    cout<<"number of array elements are : "<<size<<endl;
}
```

this function work but not perfectly. when i pass an array to this function which   has same number of elements as its size `int one[3] = {1,2,3}` or an unsized array it will return result with one more element. for example for the previous array `one[3]` it will display **number of array elements are 4**.
but in other situation it work fine. for example if I pass an array that has less element than its size `int two[4] = {1,2,3}` it will work.
I should use array in this example not **vector** or **struct** , so what should i do or what is the reason that function doesn't work with that kind of array as its parameters.

Comment: You cannot find that size. You need to pass it as an argument, use a template to pass the size or use a proper c++ container like `std::vector`. The idiomatic way of working on containers in modern c++ is to pass ranges (pairs of iterators).

Comment: Arrays are bad. They don't know their size and like to shapeshift to pointers when used as function parameters. Throw them out the window. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: `a[size] != NULL` does **not** check whether there's an element in the array at that index

Comment: as I mention i shouldn't use `vector` or `template`, so in this way there isn't any possible way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get size of dynamic array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008755/how-to-get-size-of-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: For sanity's sake replace `NULL` with `nullptr`.  If it does not compile then your are not doing it correctly.

Comment: I try to use `std::array` but it only work with fixed size array and in function parameter array should be unsize so it can accept array with different size.

Comment: @AliDK Then use `std::vector`. Variable length arrays are not allowed in portable C++ either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once an array have decayed to a pointer (to its first element), there's no way of getting its size.

The loop you have can (and most likely *will*) go out of bounds and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are three possible solutions:

1. Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead
2. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead
3. Use array-size deduction with templates:

   ```
   template<size_t N>
   int countArray(int (&a)[N]) { ... }
   ```

---

Also note that C++ doesn't have the concept of "null" values. The symbolic constant `NULL` is for *pointers* only.

Comment: as I mention I try `std::array` but it is for fixed size array and array parameter should be unsized. can I use  `std::vector` as unsized  array in function parameter? can you help with an example that how should I do this.

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't work when an array is used as a parameter, it decays into a pointer, and NULL is 0:

```
int a[5] = { 1,2,0,0,0 };
int countArray(int a[])
{
    int size = 0;
    while (a[size] != NULL)
    {
        size++;
    }
    cout << "number of array elements are : " << size << endl;
    return size;
}
```

The right answer is 5, but the output is 2.

You should change this function as follows:

```
int countArray(int a[], int size)
{
    cout << "number of array elements are : " << size << endl;
    return size;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
int a[5] = { 1,2,0,0,0 };
countArray(a, 5);
```

Comment: thank you for mentioning this point that I didn't realize before. i think I have to change the method i use because its not prefect.

Answer (score 0):

> I should use array in this example not vector or struct

From reading your comments and your inital post i just try to **guess** what data you are given and what you have to do. can it be that you are given an integer array with the following properties:

1. at least one element
2. the last element is guaranteed to be 0
3. no other element except the last is 0

Then - and only then - the solution you tried would work. The example with `int two[4] = {1,2,3}` works because you create an array with 4 elements. but only initialize 3 with aggregate initialization. so the remaining (and so the last element) is set to 0.

The check for NULL with integers works the same as a check with 0.

Comment: it is not necessary that array should has at least one element, i suppose my function work if someone pass an empty array to it and it should return zero as its number of elements. and I got your point that why function work with larger array with less elements, because remaining elements are zero which is equal to null

Comment: the problem is: if the array is empty you are not allowed to access the first element. and thats what you do unconditionally in the while loop. and again: there is NO way you can "count" the array size, except you know which value the last element has (such as a delimiter)