# How to save a string into dynamic char array

Tags: c++

- The array should be dynamic, but it is fixed.
- Printing the array gives nothing.

I'm trying to create a dynamic char array, get a string line from user, save line string char by char into the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char* lenptr = NULL;        // declare a pointer initialized with null
int leng, arrsz;
string mystr;
cout << "enter a string: ";
getline(cin, mystr);        // input a line of string
leng = mystr.length();      // get length of string
cout << "string length: " << leng << endl;
lenptr = new char[leng+1];      // declare a dynamic char array with length+1
for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++)
{
    lenptr[i]=mystr[i];     // fill array with saved string
}
lenptr[leng] = '\0';        // save '\0' in last array cell
arrsz = sizeof(lenptr);     // get size of array
cout << "size of array after saving " << leng << " chars: " << arrsz << endl;
cout << "string in array: ";
for (int j = 0; j < leng; j++)      // print array
{
    lenptr[j];
}
cout << endl;
// delete pointer
delete[] lenptr;
lenptr = NULL;  
system("pause");        // pause system
return 0;
}
```

enter a string: helloworld
string length: 10
size of array after saving 10 chars: 8
string in array:
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: "The array should be dynamic, but is fixed." Try read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/static-array-vs-dynamic-array-in-c).

Comment: Why are you not simply using `std::string`?  Is this what is being taught in a C++ course?  You even included `<string>`, which is the header file that declares `std::string`.

Comment: `arrsz = sizeof(lenptr);` -- This does not get you the number of characters.  As a matter of fact, the number of characters is totally lost when you do things this way with pointers.  That's another reason why `std::string` exists -- all of that information (such as length) is encapsulated within the class.

Comment: First, std:: is wasting time, rather
        using namespace std;
is quite useful,I believe so!
Second, thanks for GKE, your little help fixed my code issue!
Third, THANK YOU guys for NEGATIVE MARK, it's very HELPFUL! Maybe someday I'll give it back to you, also these little negative marks make me think to leave this website for good and looking for a help at useful places rather!

Answer (score 0):

[You can't get the size of an array allocated with new[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008755/how-to-get-size-of-dynamic-array-in-c). Although `std::string` is the recommended way to go about this, a vector would've been a more viable choice if the string absolutely had to be stored in a data structure.

At any rate, your program wasn't printing the characters of the array because you forgot a `std::cout` in the for loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < leng; j++)      // print array
{
    cout<<lenptr[j];
}
```

and to actually print out the size of the array just use the `leng` variable you defined earlier:

```
cout << "size of array after saving " << leng << " chars: " << leng + 1 << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah it's my fault to forget cout! The other stuff just for checking..

Comment: hope if I could do, but since people give me negative mark, I’m not able to give any feedback because my credits still less than 15!