# Printing out an entire array multiple times

Tags: c++, arrays

I am wondering how you can print out an entire array multiple times in C++. Say you have the following array:

```
arr1 = [1,2,5,6,7,8]
```

and you want to print it out n times such that the output would be:

```
1 2 5 6 7 8

1 2 5 6 7 8

1 2 5 6 7 8
```

If n would be equal to 3. You could just code some number of for loops if n is a static integer, but what if it's dynamic?

I know you need to use a for loop for printing out all the contents of an array, but I'm not sure what you would do if you want to get the above output.

Comment: If you know how to make 1 loop you can make 2 more. You can also put that one loop into a function and call it 3 times.

Comment: `[1,2,5,6,7,8]` is an invalid iniializer. Do you mean `{1,2,5,6,7,8}`? Then just loop 3 times iterating over each element outputting them space-separated, with a couple of newlines in between each successive loop.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but what if n is dynamic? In other words, what if n is some arbitrary value that the user inputs? Then, you couldn't just make some number of loops in your code or call a function some number of times manually.

Comment: What matters is the *type*. If you have used a container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then simply checking `yourvector.size()` returns the number of elements. If you are allocating/reallocating using `new/delete` - it is up to you to keep track of the number of elements. You can then loop `n` or `3` or whatever number of times required to output the elements.

Comment: @Benny I don't understand: why couldn't you do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is dynamic, it doesn't matter. You can have a loop that prints the array `n` times quite easily:

```
void printInts(int* arr, size_t size) {
    // some printing logic
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int n = 3; // could be anything really

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printInts(arr, 9);
    }
}
```

The value of `n` doesn't really matter here: it should print `n` times.

If you're asking how do we know the size of `arr` if it's a dynamic array, that's actually pretty easy too:

Until C++11:

```
size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

After C++11 you can use:

```
size_t size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

You could do this in `main()` or even in `printInts()` if you want.

**Note:** keep in mind you [can't get the size of a pointer allocated dynamically easily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22008755/10957435). If you allocate with say `new`, you'll have to keep track of the size of the array yourself.

> You can't. The size of an array allocated with new[] is not stored in any way in which it can be accessed. Note that the return type of new [] is not an array - it is a pointer (pointing to the array's first element). So if you need to know a dynamic array's length, you have to store it separately.

Comment: `size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` only good up to C++11, then you can use `size_t size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks. Fixed (I think).

Comment: (**note:** if you are obtaining the array size by either of these methods it only works on arrays (not pointers) within the scope where the array was declared)

Comment: @Benny You're welcome. If it answers your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is how to get user input:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // print array
}
```

Comment: You really need `if (c)` after using `>>`, or `n` may be uninitialised.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know how to use for loop.

```
  int rows;
  int arr1 [5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  cout << "Enter number of rows? ";
  cin >> rows;
  for(int row=1; row<=rows;row++) {

      for(int index=0;index<=4;index++) {
         // print the array index here and space after a digit
      }

      // print line-break here
  }
```

Comment: `for(int row=1; row<=rows;row++)` is more familiar to most C++ programmers in the origin 0 form `for(int row=0; row<rows;row++)` just as `for(int index=0;index<=4;index++)` will be less odd looking as `for(int index=0;index<5;index++)`. In the second case a casual reader can infer the relationship between the `5` in `int arr1 [5]` and `index<5;` far more easily than the can with `index<=4`.